# How to draw different custom data cell for each row in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an outlineview set up for ONLY 1 column with Cell based architecture for the outline view cell. I configured the cell in two ways:

- In Nib file, by setting the class type for the cell as MyCustom Cell.
- Via code, by setting the Cell in delegate class using method:
       - (NSCell *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item

I have notification set on each of my cell, and when I post a notification from somewhere, I want cell to act accordingly for the notification. Everything looks right to me while setting up the code, but when I run the code, the notification gets added for just one row. It should have been added for each row as there are many rows in my outline view.

This is how I'm setting up the notification observing in my `NSCell` subclass:

```
- (id)init {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                  name:MyNotification object:nil];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name:MyNotification object:nil];
   } 
   return self;
}

 - (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
     NSDictionary *userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
     NSString *searchString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"searchText"];
     if (searchString) {
      // Do something here 
     }
 }
```

From some other class, I am posting `MyNotification`.

Can some one please help me with whats wrong in my implementation?

Thanks in advance,
RKS

Comment: Please post the code that sets up the notification in the cell...

Comment: Here you go:
 - (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MyNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name:MyNotification object:nil];
    }
 
    return self;
}
later:

- (void) textDidChange:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
 NSString *searchString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"searchText"];

 if (searchString) {
  // Do something here
 }
}

From some other class, I am posting MyNotification.